# Why are my radio inputs not rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, radio-button

I have the following code, but it is not rendering the input tags. I have checked this by default checking a specific input, but it doesn't update the value.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react"
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"

import { UserContext } from "../userContext"


export default function UserCreateAccountForm() {
    const context = useContext(UserContext)

    const initInputs = 
    {
        userType: "",
        username: "", 
        aboutUser: "",
        profilePicture: "",
    }
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(initInputs)

    function handleChange(e) {
        const {name, value} = e.target
        setInputs(prevInputs => ({...prevInputs, [name]: value, }))
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        context.setUserData(inputs)
        // .then(() => {
        //     <Redirect to="/" />
        // })
        console.log(inputs)
    }


    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form">
            <>
            <>
            <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id="smallBusiness"
                    name="userType"
                    value="smallBusiness"
                    checked={true}
                />
            <label>Small Business</label>
            
            </>
            <input 
                type="radio"
                id="nonprofit"
                name="userType"
                value="nonprofit"
            />
            <label for="nonprofit">Nonprofit</label>
            <input 
                type="radio"
                id="supporter"
                name="userType"
                value="supporter"
            />
            <label for="supporter">{`User (someone who supports small businesses and nonprofits alike)`}</label>
            </>
            <input
                className="inputItem" 
                type="text" 
                name="username" 
                value={inputs.username} 
                onChange={handleChange} 
                placeholder="Please select a username"
            />
            <input 
                className="inputItem" 
                type="text" 
                name="aboutUser" 
                value={inputs.aboutUser} 
                onChange={handleChange}
                maxLength="142" 
                placeholder="Use 142 characters to tell us about yourself "
            />
            <input 
                className="inputItem" 
                type="file" 
                id="profilePicture"
                name="profilePicture" 
                value={inputs.profilePicture} 
                onChange={handleChange} 
            />
            <label for="profilePicture">Please choose a profile picture</label>
            <button className="inputItem">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: Double opening fragment tags <> <> but only one closing fragment tag </> ?

Comment: is there any message error that you're receiving?

Comment: @gavgrif, that was a mistake in indenting. The closing tag for the top fragment is at the bottom of all of the radio buttons.

Comment: @GrazielleCarvalho, no error, and it technically shows the input rendered in the dom tree upon inspection. However, one can't do anything with it, nor does it seem to actually exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have onChange called for the radio buttons, so they weren't updating the db. Also, there was some css styling that was hiding the buttons.